# Strings to Decimals Unable to convert

Tags: string, combobox, textbox, decimal

Please advise that I have reviewed other solution and multiple forums and NONE have worked for my problem they all refer to single strings.
Now since we got that out the way please see Problem below:
I am populating a TEXTBOX with STRING DATA. I FORMAT DATA out of the TEXTBOX and plug in into the COMBOBOX. My problem is no matter what I try it will NOT be decimal in .2 - or more. It still populates it as string(45.2323685). However when I throw a MsgBox to check the solution it works.... Solutions I have tried. "Format", "CDbl", "Prase", "Math"(after CDbl), "FormatingString", "FormatingEnabled". For some reason none would work when populating. I assume it is because of data flow since "ComboBox.Items.Add(text) populates as string and refuses to populate as decimals..... But I might be wrong. Code with Notes is below:

```
Dim countLines As Integer = TEXTBOX.Lines().Count
Dim DATA As String
If countLines > 0 Then
For x = 0 To countLines - 1
DATA = TEXTBOX.Lines(x).ToString
'MsgBox(FormatNumber(CDbl(DATA), 3)) - This works independent
   'If I try to convert DATA to DECIMAL or DOUBLE before adding to COMBOBOX 
    it throws an error invalid conversion "String to Double, String To 
    Decimal" Even if I dim DATA to something else and try to add that 
    instead
COMBOBOX.Items.Add(DATA)
Next
end if
```

Please advise if more information is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid errors by using .TryParse. The first example will add at zero to the combobox is the parse fails.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Text Box is empty")
        Return
    End If

    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        Dim d As Double
        Double.TryParse(line, d)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(d)
    Next
End Sub
```

This bit of code will simply skip the line in the textbox that fails the parse and continue adding any lines that pass.

```
    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        Dim d As Double
        If Double.TryParse(line, d) Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(d)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi, I don't really get an error. I just like to populate values as determined decimals. I know I can cheat by doing another combo box but  I was thinking if there is a legit way.